# Plone form disable main template

Tags: forms, templates, view, plone

I'm approaching to Plone in these days. I built a page with a form.

I would like to disable plone main template (not only the form template) and build my own page (with a .pt file). How can I accomplish this?

```
from Products.statusmessages.interfaces import IStatusMessage
from z3c.form import button
from z3c.form import form, field

from zope.interface import Interface
from zope.schema import TextLine
from zope.i18nmessageid import MessageFactory
_ = MessageFactory('hello_world')


class IHelloWorldForm(Interface):

    hello_world_name = TextLine(
        title=_(u'Name'),
        description=_(u'Please enter your name.'),
        required=False)


    class HelloWorldForm(form.Form):

    fields = field.Fields(IHelloWorldForm)
    ignoreContext = True

    def updateWidgets(self):
        super(HelloWorldForm, self).updateWidgets()

    @button.buttonAndHandler(u'Save')
    def handleSave(self, action):
        data, errors = self.extractData()
        if errors:
            return False

        if data['hello_world_name'] is not None:
            hello_name = data['hello_world_name']
        else:
            hello_name = 'World'

        IStatusMessage(self.request).addStatusMessage(
            "Hello %s" % hello_name,
            'info')
        redirect_url = "%s/@@hello_world_form" % self.context.absolute_url()
        self.request.response.redirect(redirect_url)

    @button.buttonAndHandler(u'Cancel')
    def handleCancel(self, action):
        IStatusMessage(self.request).addStatusMessage(
            "Hello No One",
            'info')
        redirect_url = "%s/@@hello_world_form" % self.context.absolute_url()
        self.request.response.redirect(redirect_url)

from plone.z3cform.layout import wrap_form
HelloWorldFormView = wrap_form(HelloWorldForm)
```

Comment: Please also post the imports.

Comment: What you mean? I do not understand what you are asking

Comment: I've edited. Now is more clear?

Comment: There's no question there. What are you asking?

Comment: Do you see any indication that your form does not honour a `template="..."` attribute in the `<browser:page>` declaration of your `configure.zcml`?

Comment: I would like to disable plone main template (not only the form template) and build my own page (with a .pt file)

Comment: If your template doesn't `use-macro` the main template, the main template isn't used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your own page template, by using one!

```python
from Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile import ViewPageTemplateFile

... 

class HelloWorldForm(form.Form):

    template = ViewPageTemplateFile('custom.pt')

...
```

Another solution, probably the better one, if you have to customise more than one form. 
You should  create your own form wrapper. Currently you are using the one from plone.z3cform, which obviously uses the default main_template from plone.

Follow the instructions on [plone.app.z3cform `Form main template override`](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.z3cform/tree/5d081a3087a24b430109ca0b52f6476a439d8b99#form-main-template-override)

Comment: and also disabling avoiding this line on the custom.pt file "metal:use-macro="context/main_template/macros/master"